# SQL Server Backup to Azure Storage Issues

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We are currently backing up SQL Server databases to an Azure URL as a page blob.  SQL Server version is 2012 SP3.  At times I need to get the backups to our Dev, Beta, and Test environments to be restored.  I'm having an issue with a large backup (~50 GB).  There are several smaller backups that are copied and restored okay but the one large backup is the problem.  I've tried using PowerShell scripts and AzCopy.  When attempting to restore it using the GUI, the backup is not recognized.  When attempting to RESTORE VERIFYONLY, I get the error - Msg 3013 (VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.)

If I do a restore verify from URL, the backup is valid.  If I try to restore from URL, it restores but takes forever (almost 6 hours).

Has anybody else had this problem?

Comment: `When attempting to restore it using the GUI, the backup is not recognized` It seems that backup file is destored. Have you tried to compare MD5 of the download file with blob file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the backup is not being completely copied because the AzCopy program is interrupted.
After doing a little research, I discovered there are many options to AzCopy.  One of them is the capability to resume the copy if it is interrupted.  This is handled through a PowerShell script.
AzCopy has great help - AzCopy.exe /?.